# Button starts the application, but not twice

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this application with a button ("descrição") to open a "gray background" with one text box and two buttons:
"salvar" (save button) and "cancelar" (cancel button), you can only save and close it if you type something inside the box or click on "cancelar", for the first time it works perfectly, but when you start again it doesn't open the buttons or the text box, and it stays on the "gray background".

I'm still new to HTML, CSS, and JS.

```js
$('#headerR').on('click', function() {
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeIn(500);
    $(".text-hidden").toggleClass("text");
    $(".saving").toggleClass("myButton");
    $(".canceling").toggleClass("myButton");
});



function validation() {

    if (document.getElementById("desc").value == null || document.getElementById("desc").value == "") {
        alert("Preencha a Descrição!");
    } else {
        $(function() {
            $("#save").click(function() {
                $(".text-hidden").toggleClass("text");
                $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeOut(500);
            });
        });
    }

}
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#overlay-back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    z-index: 5;
    display: none;
}

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10;
    left: 50;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
}

.text-hidden {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: 0% 40%;
    transition: all .7s ease;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.saving {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: 0% 40%;
    transition: all .9s ease;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    right: 8%;
    background: Green;
    color: white;
}

.canceling {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: 0% 40%;
    transition: all .9s ease;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: 5%;
    background: Red;
    color: white;
}

.text {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 37%;
}

.myButton {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button id="headerR" type="button">Descrição</button>
</p>
<div id="overlay-back"></div>
<div id="overlay">
  <span><script src=
  "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"
  type="text/javascript">
</script> 
  <textarea id="desc" type="textarea" class="text-hidden">
</textarea> <button id="save" class="saving" onclick=
"validation();"><span><span>Salvar</span> <button id="cancel"
  class="canceling" onclick=
  "validation();">Cancelar</button></span></button></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna only fix this bug, try this:

```js
$('#headerR').on('click', function() {
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeIn(500);
    $(".text-hidden").toggleClass("text");
    $(".saving").toggleClass("myButton");
    $(".canceling").toggleClass("myButton");
});



function validation() {

    if (document.getElementById("desc").value == null || document.getElementById("desc").value == "") {
        alert("Preencha a Descrição!");
    } else {
        $(function() {
            $(".text-hidden").toggleClass("text");
            $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeOut(500);
            $(".saving").toggleClass("myButton");
            $(".canceling").toggleClass("myButton");
        });
    }

}
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#overlay-back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    z-index: 5;
    display: none;
}

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10;
    left: 50;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
}

.text-hidden {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: 0% 40%;
    transition: all .7s ease;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.saving {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: 0% 40%;
    transition: all .9s ease;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    right: 8%;
    background: Green;
    color: white;
}

.canceling {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: 0% 40%;
    transition: all .9s ease;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: 5%;
    background: Red;
    color: white;
}

.text {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 37%;
}

.myButton {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button id="headerR" type="button">Descrição</button>
</p>
<div id="overlay-back"></div>
<div id="overlay">
  <span><script src=
  "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"
  type="text/javascript">
</script> 
  <textarea id="desc" type="textarea" class="text-hidden">
</textarea> <button id="save" class="saving" onclick=
"validation();"><span><span>Salvar</span> <button id="cancel"
  class="canceling" onclick=
  "validation();">Cancelar</button></span></button></span>
</div>
```

Comment: But of course you can improve this code. At first dont use onclick=
"validation();" function in html markup. You can hang handler in your js file, like this $('#headerR').on('click', function() {....

Comment: uAnd as you use jQuery, use jquery selectors and functions, for example you change document.getElementById("desc")  on  $("#desc").

Comment: Thanks, now I'm going to improve this code, Thank you.

Comment: I'm so happy, because I was trying to fix it one week ago, and you came and helped me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your JavaScript code as this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ece40p92/)

```js
$('#headerR').on('click', function() {
  $('#overlay').fadeIn(500);
  $('#overlay-back').fadeIn(500);
});
$(function() {
  $("#save").click(function() {
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(500);
    $('#overlay-back').fadeOut(500);
  });
});


function validation() {
  if (document.getElementById("desc").value == null || document.getElementById("desc").value == "") {
    alert("Preencha a Descrição!");
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#overlay-back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  z-index: 5;
  display: none;
}
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10;
  left: 50;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}
.text-hidden {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 0% 40%;
  transition: all .7s ease;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.saving {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 0% 40%;
  transition: all .9s ease;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  right: 8%;
  background: Green;
  color: white;
}
.canceling {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 0% 40%;
  transition: all .9s ease;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 5%;
  background: Red;
  color: white;
}
.text {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 37%;
}
.myButton {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button id="headerR" type="button">Descrição</button>
</p>
<div id="overlay-back"></div>
<div id="overlay"> <span><script src=
  "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"
  type="text/javascript">
</script> 
  <textarea id="desc" type="textarea" class="text">
</textarea> <button id="save" class="saving myButton" onclick=
"validation();"><span><span>Salvar</span> 
  <button id="cancel" class="canceling myButton" onclick="validation();">Cancelar</button>
  </span>
  </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to see what Fiddle is!

Comment: using jsFiddle you can Test and share JavaScript, CSS, HTML or CoffeeScript online.

Comment: Oh I'm using liveweave, do you think it's good too like jsFindle?

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful and polite